# 6 строк объединить в 1 строку

Tags: строки, структуры-данных, работа-с-текстом

Есть файл в таком формате (10.000 строк):

```
@alisa1
@popova1
@elmir12
@nosova1
@danya2
@kulic
@tamara25
@valentin8
```

**Возможно ли при помощи редактора, сделать 6 единиц данных в одну строку?**

К примеру: `@alisa1 @popova1 @elmir12 @nosova1 @danya2 @kulic`

 Далее еще 6 шт. и так весь файл

Comment: Какого редактора? Заменить `\n` или `\r\n` пробелом не пробовали?

Comment: потоковый редактор sed: `$ sed 'N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /g' файл > новый.файл`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, если оперировать группами и заменять их группами. Выглядит подобное конечно не очень дружелюбно:

Find: `((@\w+)(\r\n))((@\w+)(\r\n))((@\w+)(\r\n))((@\w+)(\r\n))((@\w+)(\r\n))((@\w+)(\r\n))`

Replace: `$2 $5 $8 $11 $14 $17$18`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотреть группы проще в каком-нибудь интерактивном сервисе, к примеру тут (правда заменив \r\n на \n): https://regex101.com/r/BXpW09/1/

Comment: Гораздо более дружелюбно получится, если делать в два этапа - сперва всё собрать в одну строку, а потом нарубить на строки по 6 значений. Хотя тоже так себе...